# Something wrong with Linux Mint's appearance after attempt on installing evince

Tags: package-management, cinnamon

I was trying to install the newest evince so I issued

```
add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
apt install evince
```

Which installed evince 3.24 (I think). But the borders were weird and there was something wrong with it. So I removed the PPA, purged evince, and installed it again (this time the old version 3.18 that comes in the repos).

However, all the borders (not only of evince but of the whole system) are still weird. When I installed the old version back I had to use `aptitude` instead of `apt` because `apt` told me I had broken packages so I had to downgrade 3 of them (can't remember which ones). This was my first warning that something was off.

I already issued `apt update` without the PPA but nothing is upgradable. Basically I don't know what to try.

I'm attaching some pictures of what the borders look like:

[image]

[image]

PS: I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 with cinnamon and the 4.11 kernel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you need to add that ppa again... the thing is that you can't solve the problem without knowing what you installed with evice.

Right now I believe you have 2 options, I leave them here to let you choose which one of them to use...

The easy way...

Since you don't know those 'extra' packages that you have installed with evince, maybe the easiest solution would be to make a full backup from your info and then reinstall linux mint.

The long way...

begins knowing what you did wrong, you need to add that ppa again and use this command

`apt-cache depends evince`

this will show you the packages that you need to remove from your system before updating again.

1. Make a full backup (this is always the best when you need to solve system things)
2. Remove the listed packages that you found with the command above
3. Remove the ppa
4. update your repos (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`)
5. Install the packages that you has just removed from the gnome-team's ppa (if you don't have the repo, you will install the correct packages that are stable with your system)

The reason:

Sometimes when you want to install a more "updated" package on a system that does not support it, the problem comes with the dependencies from the package, this means, if you really want that "updated" package, you need to be sure that it will be compatible with your system. In this case, it seems that all those "extra" dependencies were not compatible with your actual linux-mint

Comment: When I issue `apt-get update` it seems that nothing is updated. Now I'm missing a bunch of packages and can't update. Any tips? Also I'm getting this error: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgtk-3-0_3.18.9-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb` when I try to manually install packages.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a`, if there is no update is because your repos are synced. If that doesn't solve it, try with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104493/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-man-db) answer

Comment: I solved it by installing the packages that threw me an error manually using `--force-all`. Then I manually installed (with `apt`) every package that got uninstalled (luckily, I saved them). But I'm not sure if that means that `apt update` will work from now on. When I try your command I get a `Unknown option: a` message. I'll try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353424/375797) if I see that `update` isn't working.

Comment: Just give it a couple of days and try update again, the reason is that probably is already synced with your repos so update can't do anything right now

Comment: The installed/updated packages are probably in `/var/log/dpkg.log`. The problem is with the updated ones, the should be downgraded, not removed.