# Light pdf reader that can open multiple copies of a pdf with annotations and highlighting

Tags: linux-mint, pdf, evince

I have Linux Mint 18.2 and I have been using Evince, which is my favorite pdf reader, for a while now. But the repo version of Evince (3.18.2) has an annoying bug that makes a lot of impact for me: I can't use the "File > Open a copy" option if the pdf has highlighting. It just automatically closes itself.

I really like to use that option so I have tried installing other pdf readers but they either do not have that option or are prohibitively heavy.

Also, I installed Arch Linux in another machine, and I noticed that the latest version of Evince has that option without the bug! So I tried compiling the latest version of Evince for my Mint 18.2 but it ended up [almost breaking my system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387909/something-wrong-with-linux-mints-appearance-after-attempt-on-installing-evince) and it didn't work.

So I'm looking for a way to use that option in my Mint 18.2. As far as I know my options are

- Use another light pdf reader (I haven't found any)
- Figure out how to compile a more recent version of Evince (also couldn't do that)
- Move to Arch Linux or another system that supports a more up-to-date version of Evince (which I'm trying to avoid)

Any ideas that I can try?

Comment: I use Okular. It's quite usable, and unlike Evince, it still has customization options. But you've probably tried that already.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes! I found it was kinda bulky and slow. But I might have to resort to it if I can't get anything else.